# Is it possible to add CORS headers to response from j_security_check in Tomcat container

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, cors

Getting the following error when trying to make an ajax call from app1 which runs on port 8081 to app2 which runs on port 8088. The redirect is being blocked by browser due to CORS issue .

Failed to load http://localhost:8088/j_security_check?j_username=admin&j_password=admin: Redirect from 'http://localhost:8088/j_security_check?j_username=admin&j_password=admin to 'http://localhost:8088/resource' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
Origin 'http://localhost:8081' is therefore not allowed access.

Is there a way to add CORS header to response from customized j_security_check class?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add below filter in web.xml of tomcat

```html
<filter>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern> /* </url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

and check

Comment: I have tried this filter already. It works well with all servlets but not with j_security_check  authentication.